# parsing JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting this response in $.ajax success method.

```
{\"ID\":18,"TSName":"testSuit"}
```

How can I parse it like

```
success: function (response) {
  var tr = response.d;
  alert(tr.TSName);
```

Comment: Are you generating the JSON string? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **dataType** option of jQuery's [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) call. If you specify JSON, jQuery will parse it for you in to the object you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can pass the data to [`.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and you will get a JSON object back.

Answer (score 1):

test this:

```
$.getJSON('yoururl', function(data) {
  ...
});
```